# Wordpress - Using index.php for post and custom post type

Tags: wordpress, loops, post

I need to use my index.php file for my standard wordpress news, but also for custom post type.

In my index.php file I use a standard loop with no arguments or parameters.

I am trying to make it work with the action "pre_get_posts". I have been trying to change the query post type, but still doesn't work.

```
$query->set('post_type', 'any')
```

So I need a way for /dossiers/ to use index.php which mean I need to change the query of the loop when /dossiers/ is detected in the url.

Thanks alot!

Edit:

Here is the function I call with "pre_get_post":

```
function custom_post_types( $query ) { 
    if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->query['name'] == 'dossiers' ) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'any');

        var_dump($query);
    }   
}
```

And here is the var_dump of $query:

```
object(WP_Query)#100 (42) {
  ["query"]=>
  array(2) {
  ["page"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["name"]=>
  string(8) "dossiers"
}
["query_vars"]=>
array(46) {
  ["page"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["name"]=>
  string(8) "dossiers"
  ["error"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["m"]=>
  int(0)
  ["p"]=>
  int(0)
  ["post_parent"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["subpost"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["subpost_id"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["attachment"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["attachment_id"]=>
  int(0)
  ["static"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["pagename"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["page_id"]=>
  int(0)
  ["second"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["minute"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["hour"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["day"]=>
  int(0)
  ["monthnum"]=>
  int(0)
  ["year"]=>
  int(0)
  ["w"]=>
  int(0)
  ["category_name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["tag"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["cat"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["tag_id"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["author_name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["feed"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["tb"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["paged"]=>
  int(0)
  ["comments_popup"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["meta_key"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["meta_value"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["preview"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["s"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["sentence"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["fields"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["category__in"]=>
    array(0) {
  }
  ["category__not_in"]=>
    array(0) {
  }
  ["category__and"]=>
    array(0) {
  }
  ["post__in"]=>
    array(0) {
  }
  ["post__not_in"]=>
    array(0) {
  }
  ["tag__in"]=>
    array(0) {
  }
  ["tag__not_in"]=>
    array(0) {
  }
  ["tag__and"]=>
    array(0) {
  }
  ["tag_slug__in"]=>
    array(0) {
  }
  ["tag_slug__and"]=>
    array(0) {
  }
  ["post_type"]=>
    string(3) "any"
}
  ["tax_query"]=>
  NULL
  ["meta_query"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["post_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["current_post"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["in_the_loop"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["comment_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["current_comment"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["found_posts"]=>
  int(0)
  ["max_num_pages"]=>
  int(0)
  ["max_num_comment_pages"]=>
  int(0)
  ["is_single"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["is_preview"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_page"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_archive"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_date"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_year"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_month"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_day"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_time"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_author"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_category"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_tag"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_tax"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_search"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_feed"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_comment_feed"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_trackback"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_home"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_404"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_comments_popup"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_paged"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_admin"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_attachment"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_singular"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["is_robots"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_posts_page"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_post_type_archive"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["query_vars_hash"]=>
  string(32) "3cd80adcb57d626df6535f6dafb98057"
  ["query_vars_changed"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["thumbnails_cached"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

The value for "name" is set to "dossiers", which is supposed to be the slug for a post name, if I set it to "", I get redirected to single.php with my last custom post type.

Comment: Why can you not use a `single-{custom-post-type}.php` template file?  The way the wordpress hierarchy works index.php will always be the last template to be called.

Comment: Because it's gonna be a exact copy of index.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your conditional isn't interacting properly with the `$query` object.

Try:

```
if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->query_vars['name'] == 'dossiers' )
```

If that doesn't work, maybe this will work:

```
$query_var_name = get_query_var('name');
if( $query->is_main_query() && $query_var_name == 'dossiers' )
```

Also, add some kind of test to make sure that your index.php is actually the template file Wordpress is using when you visit /dossiers

Comment: My conditional is working, since:

["post_type"]=> string(3) "any"

is in my var_dump

Comment: That's because the Wordpress query class is smart enough to apply your `set` to the appropriate `query_var`. If you want the 'name', I'm pretty sure you'll have to get it from `query_vars`.

Comment: What I meant is... the condition is not the problem, if I remove it completely, I still don't see my custom post type when I go to /dossiers/

Comment: You've set the `post_type` query variable to `any`, so unless `any` is your custom post type, I'd imagine that's why.